# Keep revision history between folders in svn

Tags: svn

I am using svn for version control on a simple project. It is a major
mode for emacs, so it is only one file.

I want a way to maintain revision history of both development, and of code released to users, all of which is done from the same svn repository. One of my goals is a consistent URL that users can check out, and for users to always be able to run `svn update` to get the newest "release," although releases are very informal.

I currently do my development in a "devel" folder, committing changes
to devel as necessary. When changes are ready to be release, I copy
mymode.el from devel to "trunk" (perhaps a poor choice of name - this is the folder users check out) to overwrite the working copy with the new changes, and then commit to trunk.

I am pretty sure that this preserves the revision history in trunk,
but the method seems sort of kludgey and I feel like I'm not using svn
the way it's intended.

Is there a better way of either bringing changes from devel to trunk,
or perhaps of organizing my project to allow a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current style is, well, ugly:

- One of task of any SCM is easy reconstruction of the whole code evolution, but in your case, if you (did I understand you correctly?) just copy modified in more than one revision file from WC to WC - you lose relation between state of trunk and state of devel-branch: trunk work as set of tags without known parent (try to answer question "From which branch-revision I created $THIS revision in trunk" - and you'll fail)

Workflow and habits and tastes may differ. Anyway, **I** always prefer "Branch per Task" style (and create branch even for single-commit changes) and have in trunk only mergesets. For your goal "Provide permanent URL to different revision of code in repository" **I** (again, it's personal choice) prefer to use "floating" externals as published URL (with changing from time to time PEG-revision in definition). I.e it can be directory-type external definition in the root of repository ("Release", f.e), mapped to some revision of /trunk (the same for for trunk-only development or for "Branch per task" of for almost any other workflow - only linking node policy *may* change).

Your users will always get `REPOSTORY/RELEASE`, but it can be during development process /trunk@1, /trunk@10, /trunk@100 and you'll be able to see history of releases just using log ("release" means changing externals definition, thus - special commit)

Comment: I suspected this was ugly. That's why I'm looking for help! Do I understand correctly that you are recommending something like an empty `REPOSITORY/RELEASE` folder that just references a specific revision of trunk using an externals definition? Would the history of releases just be a history of the externals property or would I be able to do a diff that showed what changed between one release and the next?

Comment: @jake - exteral folder is **NOT** real, "physical" folder. It's virtual folder, which seems as folder in repo-browser (TortoiseSVN), exist as real folder in you Working Copy (if you checkouted parent of external), but it's just result of using specially constructed propset command. Do you want to see sample with screenshots and related commands added into answer?

Comment: I think I get the idea. Still curious about what history I would be able to get. Would svn log show anything besides the changing definition of the externals property?

Comment: @jake - log will not, because it's log. But if you know revisions of 2 releases, you can use log for range (**all** changed **files** between releases) of diff for range (**combined changes** in files between releases)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mark good releases, use tags. It's simpler and cleaner. The problem you have is if I request the trunk history, Subversion will go right down trunk. You won't see anything interesting that took place on the devel branch.

I prefer to do all work on trunk and to branch only when necessary. This usually means right before a release when some developers are working on the release and some are doing future work. Use tags to mark your releases.

This way you'll get the complete history and still be able to pull off your good releases.

If you're working on a feature that will take a while and you're worried that you'll muck up trunk, make a feature branch, and then merge that feature into trunk.

Comment: I read a lot of documentation about branching before posting my question, and I think it's maybe overpowered for what I need. This project will never have more than 2 or 3 developers, and "releases" won't be very formal. The "right before a release" scenario won't really apply. If I understand tags correctly, it's just a different folder, right? I don't want to make users update their URL's, as I described in the OP.

Comment: @jake - I prefer "branch per task" even in  solo-development

Comment: @jake Tags are merely _folders_, but a folder you give meaning. I have a pre-commit hook that allows you to create, but not modify a tag, making the tag more tag-like. Yes, in small shops, you don't necessarily create a release branch. I wouldn't if I didn't have to. To me, branching is merely a means of allowing parallel work. If you _tag_ your release, you can create a branch from the revision that that create a tag if you have to patch that release.