# SVN: update of a tag by remove/creation

Tags: svn

I manage a huge SVN repository, containing on-line documentation, with numerous files, with current version in a trunk section. Once a week, I perform an operation that updates the repository (trunk section). This operation takes one day to achieve. At the end I create a new tag to deploy the updates to end-users that use the repository in read-only mode.
This solution is not efficient, because, the end-users applcation has to switch to the new tag to get the updates, which can take a lot of time.
I would like to :
- either use always the same tag value, that I remove and re-create after having performed the weekly updates. In this case does the end-user application will not be lost as the tag has the same value but the content has changed (release numbers)?
- or update the content of the tag: in this case the duration of the commit can be huge and the end-users blocked during the commit operation (in fact the commit is performed in several phases to prevent from memory fault)

Thank you in advance for your answers,
Christian

Does someone can help me choosing the right solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23190022/960558 for deeper details

Comment: And - tag is RO by convention, not design. You *can* commit to tag and end-users will have always latest, HEAD version of mutable tag

Answer (score 0):

Your natural choice will be using svn:externals - you'll share permanent URL, which point in time to different tags. And switching tags is fast - you commit only property-change

Comment: I explain a bit more what I intend to do:

Comment: On the SVN repository, we have a "trunk" area that we manipulate during the week (updates, commit,...). At the end of the week, we perform a copy (svn tag function) of the trunk in the "tags" area (name: ".../tags/deploy"), after having previously removed the existing one. Then we have users with a JAVA application that connect the SVN repository (.../tags/deploy) and synchronize once a week their local data. Is this a correct method ? will the users' local working copy be always correctly synchronized, even though the target repository (.../tags/deploy) is removed and recreated once a week ?

Comment: 1. Yes, will be synced. But using svn:externals **without** re-creation tag is more fast|easy|transparent way - just se trunk with PEG-revision in external

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick answers. I have read the svn:externals documentation but I don't see how I can apply this method to our system. Please can you give me some steps to follow in my case ? Thank you in advance

Comment: @user3570927 - did you see my first comment on your question and link to my answer in another (but related by nature) topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187435/keep-revision-history-between-folders-in-svn/23190022#23190022